# How to run Laravel own unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5.5

I just installed Laravel 5.5.* using following composer commands:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"  --prefer-source
```

Here is my Laravel instalation folder:

```
╭─yusuf@yusuf-he ~/test-laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework  ‹cf750b0›

╰─➤  ls                                                                                                                                                                                        

CHANGELOG-5.4.md  CHANGELOG-5.5.md  CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  composer.json  CONTRIBUTING.md  LICENSE.md  phpunit.xml.dist  README.md  src  tests
```

And now I am wondering about how to run the unit tests that owned by the Framework it self ?

I've tried this but got another error:

```
╭─yusuf@yusuf-he ~/test-laravel/blog  ‹f4cba4f*› 

╰─➤  ./vendor/bin/phpunit  ./vendor/laravel/framework/tests    

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Tests\Integration\Database\DatabaseTestCase' not found in /home/yusuf/test-laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/tests/Integration/Database/EloquentBelongsToManyTest.php on line 16

Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Tests\Integration\Database\DatabaseTestCase' not found in /home/yusuf/test-laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/tests/Integration/Database/EloquentBelongsToManyTest.php on line 16
```

I need this to make sure that installed Laravel 5.5 is running well in my environtment.

Comment: "I need this to make sure that installed Laravel 5.5 is running well in my environtment." I guess you are doubting the framework and its contributors. My question is, simply running `php artisan serve` won't do the job for you? If there is/are any issues with respect to your installation, it will let you know then and there itself..

Comment: I mean I want to make sure all Framework functionalities are supported by my env.  I admit that I confused by "the framework and its contributors" I understand it now by doing small research and learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer by my-self, to test the Framework it self by running unit tests I need to install it from the inside of Framework folder.

```
cd ~/test-laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework
composer install
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Don't forget to set/uncomment the redis connection in php phpunit.xml

```
<env name="REDIS_HOST" value="127.0.0.1" />
<env name="REDIS_PORT" value="6379" />
```

and don't forget to make sure that your redis server is on

```
redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment database testing on the .env file and phpunit.xml

Comment: whoaaps, I forgot about that, ok then I will try and let you know about the result.

Comment: Hi, database has been configured and working well, but the unit test is still giving me same error